# How to execute an update statement from Excel macro to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have an Excel 2007 file in which I do a lot of dataprocessing (merely reporting) using remote connections to a SQL Server db. When a report has been processed I would like to update a specific field of a table that resides on the same SQL Server db. Something like:

```
UPDATE [MetricsCollection].[dbo].[tblBatchFeeder] 
SET datReportProcessed = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
WHERE intID = 48
```

What's the simplest way to approach this?

Kind regards,

Paul.

Comment: You can use ADO to do this.  Eg: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/565744-running-a-sql-update-query-in-excel-vba.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be best to have a procedure on the server.

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

cn.Open ServerConnect ''http://connectionstrings.com

cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

cmd.CommandText = "UpdateMetrics" ''stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters("@intID").Value = 48 ''Parameter
cmd.Execute recs
```

Comment: Thanks, that led me in the right direction. And you're right that's it better to use SP also. But just wanted to know the concepts. 

Came accross ADO answers before but wanted to know if this is THE method or not.